# Find vector set of all orthogonal vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

Find the vector set of all orthogonal to vectors $\vec{v}=(1, 2, 3, 4)$, $\vec{w} = (2, -2, 6, -4)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. I think orthogonal is means the vectors dot product to be $0$. I maybe can find one of the vectors, but how can I find all of them?

Comment: Put $v^T$ and $w^T$ in the columns of a $4\times 2$ matrix $A$, then find $N(A^T)$.

Comment: Once you've found 2 independent vectors in the null space the rest are just scaled versions of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the set of orthogonal vectors is such that its dot product with v and w are both 0. Choose the vector $(a, b, c, d)^T$ to represent the orthogonal vector. Take the dot product with both v and w to get $$a+2b+3c+4d=0\\2a-2b+6c-4d=0\\ \text{second equation implies } a=b-3c+2d\\\text{plug back in first equation to get }b=-2d\\\text{plug back in second equation to get }a=-3c$$

Thus the set of orthogonal vectors is $$\left(\begin{matrix}-3c\\-2d\\c\\d\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-3\\0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right)c+\left(\begin{matrix}0\\-2\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)d$$

I believe this can be called a plane in $\mathbb R^4$ as each point in the subspace has 2 degrees of freedom. Since there are 2 unique equations (neither of which is $0=0$ or $0=1)$ and which have no constant term, points in the resulting subspace will have their degree of freedom reduced by 2.